# Finding out where Powershell stdout is redirected to (as opposed to cmd.exe)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, stdout

I am trying to detect read / write cycles like the Linux program `cat` does:

```
$ cat a b c > b
cat: b: input file is output file
```

On Linux, I can identify files with the `stat` family of functions to find such a loop. Similarly on Windows, I can compare fields of the result of `GetFileInformationByHandle` - I need a `HANDLE` **to a file** for that though (handles to a pipe do not work).

This is where I am stuck. Neither of the answers in [Check if Windows file is redirected to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360969/check-if-windows-file-is-redirected-to-itself) and [How to check if stdout has been redirected to NUL on Windows (a.k.a. /dev/null on Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069853/how-to-check-if-stdout-has-been-redirected-to-nul-on-windows-a-k-a-dev-null-o) are working for me in Powershell.

I found that in `cmd.exe` (with the variable `stdout` being a handle obtained from `GetStdHandle`), `GetFileType(stdout)` is 1 (`FILE_TYPE_DISK`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29361307/13679671) from the second thread) when redirecting to a file. Here, I can do everything I could do with a file handle and there are no problems.

However in Powershell `GetFileType(stdout)` is 3 (`FILE_TYPE_PIPE`). Similarly, APIs like `GetFinalPathNameByHandleW` return a path when running under `cmd.exe` but not in PS.

I read that Powershell has cmdlets like `Out-File` for that, so I thought for a moment that ">" is maybe aliased to "`| Out-File ...`", but in the documenation it is called an operator, which to me *seems like* too strong a word for just an alias.

Can anyone explain, why the ">" operator behaves so differently on `cmd.exe` and Powershell? What can I do to work around that? Is there any way to find out where stdout (aka the success stream) is redirected to in Powershell?

---

The full (Rust) code (1 function, starting at line 44) can be found [here](https://github.com/niklasmohrin/bat/blob/detect-same-files/src/controller.rs#L44), there is some Rust safety noise around the calls into the Windows APIs though.

Comment: To answer the `>` vs. `Out-File` part: `>` isn't an alias in a strict PowerShell sense, but _in effect_ it behaves just like `Out-File`, and you can even modify its behavior via `Out-File`-targeted `$PSDefaultParameterValues` entries. Neither with `>` nor with `Out-File` is pipeline output sent as-is to a file: _string_ representations are created via PowerShell's formatting system (with objects that are already strings getting passed through, which all outputs from external programs are) and then saved to a file using `Out-File`'s default encoding, except if overridden with `-Encoding`.

Comment: Long story short: in PowerShell, `>` isn't a straight stdin-to-file conduit.

Comment: Thank you @mklement0, that makes sense! Do you know if there is a way for me to gather any information about the target of `Out-File`, or do these cmdlets run fully isolated like full-fledged executable binaries? Or is there maybe even a way to hook into the `>` operator? I really don't know much about PowerShell streams and semantics.

Comment: Fun with streams. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7
and https://petri.com/understanding-how-streams-work-in-powershell-7

Comment: @Niklas, I personally wouldn't know how to do that, and I'm not sure that it's possible (though I don't know for sure). Cmdlets run in-process and are instances of special .NET classes.

Comment: @ErykSun: They're passed through if they already are .NET strings created in PowerShell itself or via .NET methods; yes, in the case of external executables, stdout lines are converted to .NET strings (composed of UTF-16 code units) based on the encoding reported by `[Console]::OutputEncoding`. The line-by-line parsing means that the _input_ newline styles are irrelevant, because PowerShell interchangeably accepts CRLF, LF and even CR by itself as a newline. On _output_ to a file, the _platform-native_ newline sequences are used (which could in effect amount to LF -> CRLF on Windows).